# How to attach a link only for calculation with a button for my tkinter program

Tags: python, tkinter

I am making a currency converter. I want to attach the live link of currency converter calculation with a button. In this program we takes input from an Entry widget and also give output to an Entry Widget. I want to attach the link only for the calculation of currency conversion with the button. So that the currency values will auto update in that program and I don't have to add mannual calculation to program for conversion.

Please help me with this problem as I have to submit this program in my college.

Comment: Look for an API then

Comment: Is there anything else other than use of API?

Comment: Manually defining each currency rates.

Comment: That's exactly I don't want cause these values change every day.

Comment: @MDDANISH *That's exactly I don't want cause these values change every day.* Thats why you should use an API, there are services who takes care of these values. You may invent a method to predict these values, but be aware that this topic isnt new and there is no known way yet.

Comment: Maybe you can attach some codes to show us what you have than so far, so that someone can help, Viewing your problem from your perspective?

Answer (score 0):

Im new to python aswell but I feel like you can make use of modules to get uptodate currency values.

I found this on web. https://pypi.org/project/CurrencyConverter/

Comment: Thank you for your help sir. But I also don't much familiar with python cause my python course is not completed. I'll try if I can use it.